# Show that a graph with $d(u)+d(v) \geq n$ for all non-adjacent $u$ and $v$ has no cut-vertex

Tags: graph-theory

I'd like to know if someone can help me with this problem, please!! Or any idea!

Let $G$ be a graph with $n > 3$ vertices with the property $d(u)+d(v) \geq n$ (where $d(u)$ denotes the degree of vertex $u$) for any non-adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$. Show that $G$ has no cut-vertex.

Comment: Hint : The graph must contain a hamilton cycle.

Comment: See [Ore’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore's_theorem).

Comment: @Daniela Velásquez Garzón: A graph that contains a Hamilton cycle cannot contain a *cut vertex*. Do you understand why?

Comment: I haven't study a hamilton cycle yet, it's for my graph class the exercise

Comment: I saw the Ore's theorem but I still can't figure it out how to connect the ideas, I don't know if it's very simple but I'm really good proving things, can you give me a better idea please?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $u$ and $v$ are non-adjacent vertices such that $d(u) + d(v) \geq n$, what can you say about $N(u) \cap N(v)$?  (Recall that $N(u)$ denotes the set of neighbors of $u$.)